# Popup menu opened in QDialogBox crashes when AddressSanitizer is enabled on MSVC 2019

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QT 5.15 C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. When I enable the address sanitizer (/fsanitize=address) and build the project, I observe that if a file in the dialogbox is right clicked to open the popup menu, it causes a crash.
I use Visual Studio QT VS tools extension.
I assume this is a QT related bug. However, I am open to suggestions to work around this issue.
The minimum reproducible error code is given in below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Create a QWidget (window) to contain our button
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(400, 300);

    window.setWindowTitle("File Dialog Example");

    // Create a QPushButton
    QPushButton button("Open File Dialog", &window);

    // Connect a slot to the button's clicked signal
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        // Open a file dialog
        QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( // crashed line
            &window,
            "Open File",
            "",
            "All Files (*.*)"
        );
     });

    // Show the window
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```